# Python main function never calls other functions?

Tags: python, menu, while-loop, program-entry-point

I have an assignment to create a basic calculator program that has addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division as choices. Main should call menu, menu should display choices, and after an answer is displayed the program should return to the menu.

When I run it, the menu displays properly and prompts me to choose the math operation, but when I enter a value (even if it is an invalid number) the program does nothing and returns to the menu.

```
def add(num1,num2):
    num1, num2 = prompt()
    return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1,num2):
    num1, num2 = prompt()
    return num1 - num2

def multiply(num1,num2):
    num1, num2 = prompt()
    return num1 * num2

def divide(num1,num2):
    num1, num2 = prompt()
    if num1 == 0 and num2 == 0:
        print "Dividing zero by zero is undefined."
    if num1 != 0 and num2 == 0:
        print "Cannot divide by zero."
    return float(num1) / num2

def prompt():
    num1 = raw_input("Please enter the first value: ")
    num2 = raw_input("Please enter the second value: ")
    return (num1,num2)

def menu():
    print "Basic Calculator"
    print "1 - Add"
    print "2 - Subtract"
    print "3 - Multiply"
    print "4 - Divide"
    print "5 - Quit"
    operation = int(raw_input("Please enter a value to choose from options    above: "))
    return operation

def main():
    while True:
        if menu() == 1:
            answer = add(num1,num2)
            print answer
        elif menu() == 2:
            answer = subtract(num1,num2)
            print answer
        elif menu() == 3:
            answer == multiply(num1,num2)
            print answer
        elif menu() == 4:
            answer == divide(num1,num2)
            print answer
        elif menu() == 5:
            print "Thank you for using basic calculator"
            print "Goodbye!"
            break    
        else:
            print "Invalid input"

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

How do I get the main function to call the add, subtract, multiplication, and division functions, and then break if option 5 is selected to quit?

I'll add that I'm new to python. Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in main, change to this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        operation = menu()
        if operation == 1:
            answer = add(num1,num2)
            print answer
        elif operation  == 2:
            answer = subtract(num1,num2)
            print answer
        # And so on
```

Because you called menu() on every IF you only checked one IF per input.

**EDIT**

Remove all your inputs to your functions: `def add(num1,num2)` should be `def add():` because they return values, they don't take values.

Comment: Now it should get an error. Since num1 and num2 is not defined at the point add/sub etc. called.

Comment: @Tichodroma You are wrong, you can't call it in every if because then you get a prompt for every if statement.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem, but brought light to others... on with the troubleshooting!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I discovered I need all my raw input to be assigned as a numerical value. It's adding 1 and 3 to 13 because it sees them as string variables.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't catch that one :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. But your code does not work because lines like this

```
answer = add(num1,num2)
```

throw an error:

```
$ python2 so.py    
Basic Calculator
1 - Add
2 - Subtract
3 - Multiply
4 - Divide
5 - Quit
Please enter a value to choose from options    above: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "so.py", line 39, in main
    answer = add(num1,num2)
NameError: global name 'num1' is not defined
```

Where do you think `num1` and `num2` come from?

Comment: I'm trying to set the variable answer equal to what the add functions returns. I see now that num1 and num2 are local variables within add... How should I call add? Simply add() ?

Comment: Yes, simply call  `add()` . Inside this function, `promp()` will prompt the user for the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You invoked a function with parameters that doesn't exist yet: `add(num1, num2).` From the snippet below, `num1` and `num2` is not yet defined since they are initialized by the function `prompt()`, which is called by the other functions(`add()`, `subtract()`, etc).

```
def main():
    while True:
        if menu() == 1:
            answer = add(num1,num2)
            print answer
```

Initialize `num1` and `num2` first before using them as parameters in your subsequent calls. Remove the call to prompt() inside the other functions. Something along the lines of calling `prompt()` first before using them in a function call:

```
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1 + num2

...

def main():
    while True:
        if menu() == 1:
            num1, num2 = prompt()
            answer = add(num1,num2)
            print answer
```

Basically, modify your thinking a little bit. Parameters that you pass into a function call, in your case `num1` and `num2` passed into `add(num1, num2)`, should have been already initialized. That is, `num1` and `num2` should already have values before you pass them into another function, say `add(num1, num2).`

Also, `raw_input()` returns a string so you must convert them into numerical values first before you can do mathematical operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Simple maths count")
num1 = int(input("What is your number?"))
for i in range (1, 20):
    print (num1 * i)
```

Comment: You should use the code formatter to display this nicely

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.